# IN only matches on first value when using STRING_SPLIT

Tags: sql-server, split, sql-server-2016

I have a varchar of comma separated values. I am attempting to check if a value is in the comma separated list.

For instance, if the varchar is 'AAA, BBB, CCC', checking for 'BBB' should return true.

I am using STRING_SPLIT to parse the commas separated list, but matching is only working as I expect on the first value:

```
DECLARE @List VARCHAR(100) = 'AAA, BBB, CCC'

SELECT
CASE    
    WHEN 'AAA' IN (SELECT VALUE FROM STRING_SPLIT(@List, ',')) THEN 'true'
    ELSE 'false'
END
--selects true


SELECT
CASE    
    WHEN 'BBB' IN (SELECT VALUE FROM STRING_SPLIT(@List, ',')) THEN 'true'
    ELSE 'false'
END
--selects false
```

As you can see from this [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdgIF.png), STRING_SPLIT is splitting all of the values as expected. Why is IN only checking for the first one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its because you have *Leading* space in the `list` for each item except **first** item.

Use `LTRIM` in the `SPLIT_STRING` function result to remove the leading space

```
DECLARE @List VARCHAR(100) = 'AAA, BBB, CCC'

SELECT
CASE    
    WHEN 'BBB' IN (SELECT LTRIM(VALUE) FROM STRING_SPLIT(@List, ',')) THEN 'true'
    ELSE 'false'
END
```

**Result :** `true`

Comment: Whoops. Devil is in the details, as usual. Thanks you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

There is space in your ' BBB' hence the issue, if you use below it works fine

```
DECLARE @List VARCHAR(100) = 'AAA, BBB, CCC'

SELECT VALUE FROM STRING_SPLIT(@List, ',')

SELECT
CASE    
    WHEN 'AAA' IN (SELECT VALUE FROM STRING_SPLIT(@List, ',')) THEN 'true'
    ELSE 'false'
END
--selects true


SELECT
CASE    
    WHEN ' BBB' IN (SELECT VALUE FROM STRING_SPLIT(@List, ',')) THEN 'true'
    ELSE 'false'
END
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I accepted @Prdp's as he beat you to the punch, but I really appreciate you taking the time to provide the info.

Comment: Welcome... Appreciate best answer.. i too thought ltrim is better way after looking at that...